# Работа с фрагментами Android

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь использовать фрагменты в приложении.
Первый фрагмент отображает картинку, второй текст. При запуске устанавливается фрагмент с картинкой, при выборе в боковом меню `Drawer` картинка в фрагмент устанавливается, все отлично, затем нажимаю по кнопке в активити (метод `onClick`), фрагмент с картинкой заменяется на второй фрагмент с текстом и происходит работа там, тоже все отлично. Но вот когда затем снова кликаю по пункту в боковом меню, то получаю ошибку `NPE` в строке `((ImageView) frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_horoicon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.oven);` (также указал комментом в коде), хотя вроде перед `switch`ем произвел смену фрагмента с текстом на фрагмент с картинкой. Подскажите пожалуйста, где кроется ошибка? Спасибо.

P.S. для бокового меню используется библиотека [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.DividerDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Drawer drawer;
    Fragment_image frag_image;
    Fragment_text frag_text;
    FragmentTransaction frag_trans;
    Button button_yesterday;
    String link;
    String prelink;
    Parser par;
    String text;
    String date;
    Fragment frag;

    public void onClick(View view) {

        frag_trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        frag_trans.replace(R.id.frag_container, frag_text); // заменяем фрагмент с картинкой на фрагмент с текстом
        frag_trans.commit();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_yesterday:
                link = prelink + "yesterday.html";
                break;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frag_image = new Fragment_image();
        frag_text = new Fragment_text();

        button_yesterday = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_yesterday);

        frag_trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        frag_trans.add(R.id.frag_container, frag_image); // устанавливаем первый фрагмент с картинкой
        frag_trans.commit();
        frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container);

        PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName(R.string.select_sign).withSelectable(false);
        SecondaryDrawerItem item2 = (SecondaryDrawerItem) new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName(R.string.oven);

        drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .withSelectedItem(-1)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        item1,
                        new DividerDrawerItem(),
                        item2
                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                        frag_trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        frag_trans.replace(R.id.frag_container, frag_image); // при клике в боковом меню по пункту списка устанавливаем фрагмент с картинкой и подгружаю картинку в ImageView
                        frag_trans.commit();
                        frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container);

                        switch ((int) drawerItem.getIdentifier()) {
                            case 2:
                                ((ImageView) frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_horoicon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.oven); // тут получаю NPE
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

**UPD**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment_image frag_image;
    Fragment_text frag_text;
    FragmentTransaction frag_trans;
    Fragment frag;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frag_image = new Fragment_image();
        frag_text = new Fragment_text();

        frag_trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        frag_trans.add(R.id.frag_container, frag_image);
        frag_trans.commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ((ImageView)frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_horoicon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.choose_sign);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Аохоже что там у вас не тот фрагмент, который вы ожидаете. Проверьте конкретный класс фрагмента в момнт нажатия и ищите ошибку в логике

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, при запуске фрагмент картинки нормально ведь отрабатывает, на фрагмент текста тоже меняется нормально, а вот обратно на фрагмент с картинкой выбивает ошибку. Хотя ведь перед свитчем в Drawer меняю фрагмент `frag_trans.replace(R.id.frag_container, frag_image);` Если первый раз картинка отрабатывает, значит с самим классом фрагмента все нормально. Ранее с фрагментами не работал, поэтому подозрения, что где то ошибку допускаю в принципах смены фрагментов.

Comment: Commit работает не синхронно. По сему фоагмент моет не успеть замениться. Вообще ваш способ обращения к разметке фрагмента не верен. Но попробуйте вызвать commitNow вместо просто коммиь

Comment: @ЮрийСПб `commitNow` нет такого метода... есть только `.commitAllowingStateLoss()`. Использую `android.app.Fragment`. По поводу обращения к разметке, делал по [этому уроку](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/175-urok-105-android-3-fragments-dinamicheskaja-rabota.html)

Comment: У фрагмента появляется `View` после того, как у него вызовется getView(). До этого момента View фрагмента не инициализирован. Т. к. замена фрагмента происходит не синхронно, то и View у фрагмента инициализируется спустя какое-то время. А вы пытаетесь к нему обращаться сразу же.

Comment: @Pollux, commitNow есть, хотя, возможно, только для Support фрагментов/мэнеджера. Попробуйте ещё тогда fragmentManger.executePendingTrasactions(). У вас проблема в том, что, как верно отмечено выше дважды, операции с фрагментами происходят не синхронно. И разметки ещё нет на момент обращения к ней

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а можно ли как то засинхронизировать сие? Или может подскажете более лучший способ...

Comment: @Pollux, попробуйте fragmentManger.executePendingTrasactions() из коммента выше поставить сразу после коммита

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, и в очередной раз Вы меня выручаете) Спасибо Вам огромное! Добавил после коммита `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` и все заработало. Пожалуйста, напишите как ответ, отмечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` сразу после `commit()`. У вас проблема в том, что, операции с фрагментами происходят не синхронно. И разметки ещё нет на момент обращения к ней. А этот метод вызовет немедленное, синхронное исполнение всех текущих транзакций

Comment: Не хотел создавать такую же тему, но очень хочу спросить у Вас. Рассматриваемый кусок кода обновил в первом посте после **UPD**. Вот понадобилось мне при запуске приложения установить картинку в контейнер. Сделал вроде все как положено, добавил `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`, но опять же на строке `((ImageView)frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_horoicon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.choose_sign);` начало крашится с NPE. Думаю надо добавить паузу, чтоб контейнер успел прогрузиться.. Добавил паузу с помощью `Handler` и тогда заработало.

Comment: Но вот интересный момент: если убираю строку `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` и ставлю паузу хоть даже 5 секунд в `Handler` (ну думаю чтоб наверняка контейнер успел загрузиться) и в итоге по прошествии 5 секунд опять тот же краш... Теперь вообще для меня непонятица почему оно все таки крашится, если времени прошло куча... И почему же тут не прокатывает `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`...

Comment: @Pollux, думаю, если не вызывать синхронное исполнение транзакции, то вы, ища фрагмент по ID получаете старый фрагмент, а в нём вашего ImageView нет. Попробуйте искать фрагмент также в отложенной задаче, а не перед ней

Comment: Выше постом Вы говорили, что я неправильно обращаюсь к разметке. Может я использую устаревшие методы и оттого и эти ошибки. Может подскажете как это правильно делать, чтобы небыло таких ошибок или знаете где почитать об этом?

Comment: @Pollux, ну... Тут долго рассказывать. Я бы сейчас это через MVP сделал бы. Так надо было бы менять лишь состояние презентера, указывая ему какую картинку он показывать должен. А фрагмент при создании/активации из презентера бы брал инфу. Так вы непосредственно фрагментом бы не манипулировали и эта проблема бы не возникла

Comment: Ну в моем случае в одной и той же активити на одном и том же месте надо отображать в одном случае текст, в другом случае картинку. Поэтому без манипуляций фрагментами не обойтись, надо их при необходимости чередовать.

Comment: @Pollux, я имею в виду, что вы просто меняете фрагменты, а они уже сами при появлении на экране меняют у себя текст/картинку. Т.е. напрямую вы сами фрагменты менять не будете

Comment: А, понял, т.е. ставить картинку в коде фрагмента. Но вот у меня картинка меняется из бокового меню `Drawer`, оно в основной активити, вот и приходится из основной активити "стучаться" до компонента `ImageView` во фрагменте.

Comment: @Pollux, создайте класс, который будет хранить ID нужной картинки. Создайте интерфейс, который будет иметь метод установки картинки. Реализуйте этот интерфейс во фрагменте. В помянутом классе сделайте метод для назначения/убирания интерфейса. При присвоении интерфейса вызывайте его метод установки картинки. Из активити классу присваивайте нужную картинку. Во фрагменте в onResume передавайте его в класс. Так у вас не будет нужды обращаться ко фрагменту напрямую, фрагмент всегда будет иметь нужную картинку и это называтся MVP

Comment: Спасибо! Очень интересно! Попробую)